# is there a way to create single set-up/installable for some 5 ssis packages?

Tags: ssis, bids

we have multiple ssis packages that need to be deployed on server .. is there a way to install all these together, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create a Deployment Manifest which will let you install all the packages in a project.  To create this, you need to select the project Properties (on the Project menu), then select Deployment Utility and set CreateDeploymentUtility to True.  By default, the path for this will be bin\Deployment under your project path.  You can then copy everything in that folder to your destination and double-click the .SSISDeploymentManifest file to begin the install.

Alternatively, if you have sufficient rights, you can deploy a project directly from BIDS by entering the relevant destination server details in the project property pages (by right-clicking on the project name in Solution Explorer), then right-click and Deploy.

Comment: well..i shud try that! thanks revelator.. I created these packages invidiually.. But i guess i shud create a 'new proj' and add these 5 to that project.. and then perhaps will get to use a single config file as well?!

Comment: Yes if you put all your packages in the same project, you'll be able to create one config file that they can share.